# Generic Foreign Keys and get_or_create in django 1.0: Broken?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

As you can see, create() works, but get_or_create() doesn't. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
In [7]: f = FeedItem.objects.create(source=u, dest=q, type="greata")

In [8]: f, created = FeedItem.objects.get_or_create(source=u, dest=q, type="greata")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FieldError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/andrew/clownfish/panda-repo/community-feed/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in get_or_create(self, **kwargs)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in get_or_create(self, **kwargs)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in filter(self, *args, **kwargs)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in add_q(self, q_object, used_aliases)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in add_filter(self, filter_expr, connector, negate, trim, can_reuse, process_extras)

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in setup_joins(self, names, opts, alias, dupe_multis, allow_many, allow_explicit_fk, can_reuse, negate, process_extras)

FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'source' into field. Choices are: dest_content_type, dest_object_id, id, src_content_type, src_object_id, timestamp, type, weight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like there's different logic used in `create` and `get_or_create` as in `get_or_create` there is no `source` argument but `src_object_id` and `src_content_type` but it is easy to resolve this - pass `scr_object_id` as `u.id` and `src_content_type` as `u.content_type` (same with dest).

Or use `try/except` & `create`.

Comment: Be careful with reimplementing your own get_or_create using try/except and create. It's very easy to create a race condition that will result in errors only under live concurrent load. Examine the get_or_create source to see how it deals with that problem.